# Implementing step-by-step animation in JavaFX 2

Tags: java, animation, javafx-2

I would like to implement animation in JavaFX 2 which changes the opacity of a Text node with a given step.

Let's say, I have a Text node which opacity is 1.0d, after 500 millis I want this node's opacity to become 0.86d, after another delay of 500 millis the opacity becomes 0.72 and so on... until the opacity reaches 0.0d. A transition between these states (key frames) shouldn't exist, i.e. the animation should go ONLY through the key frames changing the opacity state of the text node.

Is this possible using the Timeline-based animation in JavaFX 2?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of approaches to implement this:

1. Provide multiple [KeyFrames](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html) to your timeline and explicitly set the opacity  in each KeyFrame by supplying a [KeyValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/KeyValue.html) to the frame OR
2. Supply a [single KeyFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/KeyValue.html#KeyValue%28javafx.beans.value.WritableValue,%20T,%20javafx.animation.Interpolator%29) with a custom [Interpolator](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Interpolator.html) subclass which you write by subclassing Interpolator and implementing the [curve](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Interpolator.html#curve%28double%29) function.
3. Nest a series of [FadeTransitions](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/FadeTransition.html) in a [SequentialTransition](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/SequentialTransition.html).  Each FadeTransition should have the same from and to values, and each these values should be lower than the values in the prior FadeTransition.

Comment: The issue at option 1 and 3 is that will make the node's opacity goes smoothly from 1.0d to 0.0d as a final result. What I would like to achieve is that from the starting value of 1.0d to get to the value 0.86d after 500millis delay without any transition. Think of these different opacity values as states which the animation jumps over at every 500millis.

Comment: Currently I am experimenting with option 2. In case of success, I will update my question.